# How to set Data Import Handler and Scheduler using solrJ Client

Tags: solr, rdbms, solrj, dataimporthandler

I am new to solr search,  i have completed a simple search.

Now I want to index documents directly from Database and want set scheduler or trigger for updating index when there is  any change in DB.

I know that I can do it with DataImportHandler but can't understand its flow.

can you help me that from which steps I should have to start this process?

or can anyone just give me pointers to do this ??

I want to do this all things using SolrJ client.

Comment: You really don't need SolrJ to invoke DIH (but you can, by setting the `/import` endpoint as your requesthandler and adding custom parameters), as it's just a single call to an HTTP endpoint. Scheduling will be to run your trigger script (or curl, wget, etc.) from something like cron. What have you tried? How are you detecting changes to your database?

Comment: I have successfully imported data but if I run query it shows 0 document

Comment: So how do you know you've successfully imported data? What query are you running? What does `numDocs` for the collection/core say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do simple edit and delete function on button click event and 
send the id with that url in servlet and do your jdbc opertaion

after that successfully commited, call your data import command from solrj and redirect it to your index page

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

This task requires many parts to work together. Work through https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler

Answer (score 0):

[`DataImportHandler`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/uploading-structured-data-store-data-with-the-data-import-handler.html) is a Solr component, which means that it runs inside the Solr instance. All you have to do is configure Solr and than run the DHI through the [`Dataimport Screen`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/dataimport-screen.html).

On the other hand [`SolrJ`](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/using-solrj.html) is an API that makes it easy for Java applications to talk to Solr. So you can write your own applications that create, modify, search and delete documents to Solr.

Comment: I have successfully imported data but there is still 0 documents I am getting.

Comment: Try adding in your post more info about the schema and the configuration you’re using.